# Jinjava first app java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, jinjava

I'm trying to create jinjava application:
src/main/java/com/company/Main.java

```
package com.company;
import com.hubspot.jinjava.Jinjava;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Jinjava jinjava = new Jinjava();
    }
}
```

and part of pom.xml (thanks to sof, i cannot post it wholly):

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>osssonatype</id>
            <name>OSS Sonatype</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hubspot.jinjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>jinjava</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.company.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
        <finalName>jj4</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

But after "mvn clean install" and "java -jar target/jj4.jar" I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hubspot/jinjava/Jinjava
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hubspot.jinjava.Jinjava
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You're not building a "fat" JAR (for instance by using the assembly plugin), so your dependencies are not included in your `jj4.jar` file, hence the `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: Thank you! I've used maven-shade-plugin to do this and now it builds.

Comment: If you are using eclipse  export as runnable jar and whether it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this can be any help.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>class name along with package which has the main method</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```